# How to convert binary string to integer in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would need to convert a binary string (actually string) column to its integer representation:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| binary_string (string)    |   integer (int64) <- What I need |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| '1011011100111000'        |   46904                          |
| '1111111111101011'        |   65515                          |
| '0111111001001010'        |   32330                          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my case the values are 16 bit max.

It's the equivalent to javascript code: `parseInt('0111111001001010', 2)`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function binary2int(x string) returns int64
language js as r'''
  return parseInt(x, 2);
''';
select *, binary2int(binary_string) as integer
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question as

```
with your_table as (
  select '1011011100111000' binary_string union all
  select '1111111111101011' union all
  select '0111111001001010' 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Try [bqutil.fn.from_binary](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community#from_binaryvalue-string):

```
select bqutil.fn.from_binary('1011011100111000')
```

[image]